# Why does xparse manual talk people into thinking that reliable expandable checking for optional arguments is possible?

Tags: expansion, xparse, optional-arguments

**There is no expandable method for reliably looking at the next token of the input stream.**

**So why does xparse manual talk people into thinking that reliable expandable checking for optional arguments is possible?**

Below you see that xparse's scanning for optional argument is flawed with `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`.

If it was not flawed then what you get with `\TestB` would be the same as what you get with `\TestA`.

I suppose it has to do with `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` using macro-argument-based methods for looking at the next token whereby curly braces are stripped off and therefore are not detected.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\TestA}{O{default}m}{This is optional: (#1). This is not optional (#2).}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\TestB}{O{default}m}{This is optional: (#1). This is not optional (#2).}

\documentclass{article}

\parindent=0ex
\parskip=\baselineskip

\begin{document}

Okay:

\verb|\TestA[optional]{not optional}|:\\
\TestA[optional]{not optional}

Okay:

\verb|\TestB[optional]{not optional}|:\\
\TestB[optional]{not optional}

\noindent\hrule\hfill\\Okay:

\verb|\TestA{[}{!!!Not an argument!!!}]{!!!Not an argument!!!}|:\\
\TestA{[}{!!!Not an argument!!!}]{!!!Not an argument!!!}

Flawed:

\verb|\TestB{[}{!!!Not an argument!!!}]{!!!Not an argument!!!}|:\\
\TestB{[}{!!!Not an argument!!!}]{!!!Not an argument!!!}

With \verb|\TestB| you should get the same as with \verb|\TestA| !!!


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could read the xparse manual section where the expandable declarations are introduced which documents this explicitly `it is not possible to differentiate between, for example \foo[ and \foo{[}: in both
cases the [ will be interpreted as the start of an optional argument.`

Comment: Given that what you show is the documented behaviour, what answer do you want to the question?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I had known a comment was coming from David Carlisle, I would have spared the community my answer. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Section "3.3 Fully-expandable document commands" of the **[current xparse manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf#subsection.0.3.3)** clearly says:

> It is not possible to differentiate between, for example `\foo[` and `\foo{[}`: in both cases the `[` will be interpreted as the start of an optional argument. As a result, checking for optional arguments is less robust than in the standard version

So I don't think that there is some "talking into thinking that..."

Answer (score 6):

The standard approach for `\NewDocumentCommand` is to create protected macros which can therefore use the TeX primitive `\futurelet`, and thus can differentiate between `\foo[...` and `\foo{[}...`. As the documentation seeks to explain, this is usually the best choice: the number of places where one needs an expandable document command are limited. (Originally we hoped they were *extremely* limited, but it turns out that's not quite true.)

It *is* possible to look expandably for a range of argument cases, and there are places one needs to do that. A standard example is at the start of a table cell, which are usually implemented ultimately using the `\halign` primitive. Another, more tricky, case is where a document command is used in a context that needs to be converted to a 'string': one sees this for example in creating (PDF) bookmarks. Whilst there are a number of approaches to these cases, having a way of 'falling back' on an expandable-but-imperfect approach to testing for arguments is one of the clearest.

As noted in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611851/73), the documentation is clear that there is a limitation to expandable argument testing. The only alternative to that, at least without going LuaTeX-only, is to omit any support for optional arguments for expandable commands. To the LaTeX team, the balance fell on the side of a documented restriction.

Comment: You say "the number of places where one needs an expandable document command are limited. "  Indeed. And the number of places where one needs an expandable document command that processes optional arguments is even more limited.  :-)  If someone needs expandable commands with optional arguments, then the suspicion is evident that somewhere conceptions are mixed which should not be mixed.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Like I said, something like a bookmark is one. Take `siunitx`: if you have `\qty[...]{10}{\metre}` in a heading, I need a way of parsing this to give a 'string' even though the `[...]` is 'thrown away'.

Comment: That's right. In case the heading is to go into a bookmark, probably `\texorpdfstring` can be used for avoiding non-expandable commands in pdf-strigs. However, this in turn requires the end user to have the expertise to know exactly which arguments from which macros could also be used for pdf strings...

Comment: @UlrichDiez There are various possibles, but ideally having to manually mark up each use case is a fallback. One could do a lot of this in `xparse`, or could do some kind of token-by-token system based on `unravel`, or ... It's something we are working on.

Comment: Really???? Is there something you /the latex3-team is not working on? :-)

Comment: Perhaps all macro-writers on/for user-level should -- from the start -- always include case selections into their macros related to the situations in which the macros are carried out. (Situations could be e.g.: creating a pdf-string, evaluating a `\pgfmathparse` expression, writing a cross-referencing label, ...). Related to this, appropriate error message if a macro is expanded in a situation for which it is not intended/for which no branch exists.  Problem of outputting error messages in expansion contexts... Problem of detecting situations... :-)